# access child database in firebase always returns null using android studio & kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I've been having problems accessing this child database in firebase, it always returns null, been searching online for days and still got no answer...here's my code, I'm using Kotlin and Firebase:

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
databaseReference = database?.reference!!.child("users")
val nikReference = databaseReference?.child("nik")
val mainDB = nikReference?.child("jabatan")

val user = auth.currentUser
etEmailUserShow.text = user?.email

   mainDB?.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
     override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
           etValidasiLamaran.text = "Jabatan - - > "+snapshot.child("jabatan").value.toString() //<<-- this one returns null
            }
```

heres my database configuration

[image: firebase capture]

Te structure is users/nik/... (the one I've highlighted red in the screenshot is nik).
What I want to access is the value likes of : berkas,ijasah,jabatan,etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to display the data under a specific user, you have to create a reference that points exactly to that user. That being said, to display the data of the first user, please use the following lines of code:

```
val db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val nikRef = db.child("users").child("753951852")
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val jabatan = snapshot.child("jabatan").getValue(String::class.java)
        Log.d("TAG", jabatan)
        etValidasiLamaran.text = "Jabatan - - > " + jabatan
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", error.getMessage()) //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
}
nikRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
POSISI : MASTER
```

Comment: Good to hear that, Andri! Can I help you with other information?